# select optgroup inside optgroup not work in vuejs?

Tags: html, vue.js, optgroup

Why it doesn't work in vuejs??

But it works in html...

```
<select>
     <optgroup label="Level_1">
           <optgroup label="Level_2">
                 <option value="option_1">option_1</option>
                 <option value="option_2">option_2</option>
           </optgroup>
     </optgroup>
</select>
```